# OrientDB migration from 2.0.12 to 2.2.18

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb, factory-pattern, orientdb2.2, orientdb-2.1

I was using below API for fetching the vertex in 2.0.12 and it was working

```java
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:172.21.112.228/mydb", "root", "root").setupPool(1,50);
        OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();
graph.getVertices("Test.name","zyx");
```

But with the latest 2.2.18, when I tried with

```java
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("memory:172.21.112.228/mydb", "root", "root").setupPool(1,50);
        OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx();
graph.getVertices("Test.name","zyx");
```

I am getting below error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
OClass not found in the schema: Test
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.getVertices(OrientBaseGraph.java:814)
    at test.GetOrientDBData.main(GetOrientDBData.java:57)
```

Comment: How you performed the migration?

Comment: Have not migrated. Running code on each setup (2.0.12 and 2.2.18). Any reference on when to use memory and remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("memory:mydb", 
     "root", "root").setupPool(1,50); 
OrientGraphNoTx graph = factory.getNoTx(); 
if(g.getVertexType("Test") == null){
  g.createVertexType("Test");
}
graph.getVertices("Test.name","zyx");
```

Two changes on your code:

1. removed the IP in the memory: URL, no need for that
2. added a check to make sure that Test class exists and in case create it